# How to save the images associated to an article?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Lets say a user can create articles and upload images to this article. What I need is this:

1. User can upload images to an article.
2. Each image should be available at least in three sizes. small, medium, large.

Since calling getServingUrl() on each request is not a good option, should I then just create three getServingUrl() for each size and image and then save these urls in the `image` database?

1. Is this the right approach?
2. Should I save anything else in the database? maybe the filenames?

Example

```
    article  |  url                                
-------------+-------------------------------------
    1        |  img1: result of getServingUrl() //small
    1        |  img1: result of getServingUrl() //medium
    1        |  img1: result of getServingUrl() //large
    1        |  img2: result of getServingUrl() //small
    1        |  img2: result of getServingUrl() //medium
    1        |  img2: result of getServingUrl() //large
```

Im Using GAE PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `=sXX` to the end of the URL you get back to have the image resized for you when you request it. Now you can just save one URL (the original) and append the correct size when you generate the HTML. It'll then be resized as it's served to the user.

You can also resize them upon creation.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

The point of getservingURL is that you call it once only, and re-use the URL over and over. Once created it persists until you remove it by calling [delete serving url.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_delete_serving_url)

EDIT: Please tag your questions, just seen your "PHP" comment.